# Something confusing about ruby parameter-passing

Tags: ruby, variables, parameters, parameter-passing, scope

I've wrote two ruby files for test

test.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def foo(bar)
    bar['key'] = 'value'
end

def my_print(a)
    a.each{|k,v|
        puts "#{k} => #{v}"
    }
end
```

test_drive.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'test.rb'

hash_test = Hash.new

foo(hash_test)

my_print(hash_test)
```

It works as what I expect, the output is

> key => value

But when I chanege the test.rb to

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def foo(bar)
    pre_defined = {'key' => 'value'}
    bar = pre_defined
end

def my_print(a)
    a.each{|k,v|
        puts "#{k} => #{v}"
    }
end
```

Here I used a pre-defined hash, but now it outputs nothing. The "hash_test" is now an empty hash. 
Please illustrate me why indeed does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple answer:

In ruby you pass variables with Objects by reference. When you assign an Object to a variable, the variable does not really contain the Object itself within it. Instead, it contains only a reference to that Object.

It may help for you to start seeing the differences between references and objects in order to understand how sending variables as parameters works: the Object itself does not reside in the variable, the variable is pointing to a reference of the Object in memory, because of this, if one variable points to another object and modifies it, that doesn't mean it modified the Object that it was previously referring to.

The important thing for you to understand is that the bar parameter in the foo method is really only a REFERENCE to the Object in memory, not the Object itself. So if bar once pointed to the Object, but it's now referencing another Object, it will modify what it is referencing, not the previous object it pointed to. Here's the code of the last test.rb commented slightly for you to understand it better:

```
def foo(bar) # here "bar" points to the same object as "hash_test"
    pre_defined = {'key' => 'value'}  # here a new object is created and referenced
    bar = pre_defined # now "bar" points to a new object and forgets about "hash_test"
end

def my_print(a) # here "a" holds a reference to "hash_test" which is empty
    a.each{|k,v|  # "a" is empty, so it has nothing to put
        puts "#{k} => #{v}" 
    }
end
```

I hope this helps. In case you need something a little more detailed:

The reason your last version of test.rb prints an empty hash in test_drive.rb is because the Hash Object that the reference "hash_test" points to is not really being modified at all. Instead the foo method, while initially receiving as a parameter called "bar" a reference of the Hash Object that "hash_test" points to, quickly replaces that reference in "bar" with a brand new reference to a brand new Hash Object that the "pre_defined" variable points to. Now "bar" doesn't point to the same Object as "hash_test" does, and so the Object that "hash_test" points to is never being modified. Thus, the Hash Object that "hash_test" contains is never really populated with anything, and is empty when my_print tries to print it.

Comment: Thanks! It really helps a lot. But it is said that the variable whose type/class is fixnum, true/false etc. holds the value in it. Is it right?

Comment: As i've come to understand it, in Ruby you have no primitive types. A variable that is considered to have a type class Fixnum is actually a reference to an instance of Fixnum which represents an integer.
Ruby is implemented in C, so primitives do
exist behind the scenes, but there is no way to access a pure
primitive type in Ruby code as far as I'm aware of. Go into irb and try a = 5 and b = 5, then do a.object_id. They're both referring to the same object: a.object_id, b.object_id, try 5.object_id and also 5.class, 5.methods.

Comment: Just to confirm, Fixnum and True/False are Objects. Just try this little snippet in irb for confirmation:  5.class.ancestors  and also true.class.ancestors and false.class.ancestors

Comment: Ruby is *not* pass-by-reference, it is pass-by-value. Always. No exceptions. If it *were* pass-by-reference, then we wouldn't have this conversation because @fabregaszy's code would have worked as he expected and he never would have asked this question. Don't believe me? Ask Ruby: `def foo(bar) bar = 'reference' end; baz = 'value'; foo(baz); puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}"`

Comment: @fabregaszy: The difference between pass-by-value where the value being passed is a pointer to an object and pass-by-value where the value is being passed directly can only be observed for mutable objects. Since `Fixnum`s, `Symbol`s etc. are *immutable*, it is impossible to tell whether they are passed directly or indirectly. The fact that MRI, YARV, Rubinius etc. choose to implement passing them by passing around native CPU integers directly is a performance optimization. For your mental model, they are passed the same way as any other object, that's one less corner case to think about.

Answer (score 1):

That is, because Ruby is pass by value, whereby the reference of an object is passed. It’s a similar behavior of what Java does. That means that you have only a copy of the reference within the foo-method and reassigning it does not change the reference outside of this method.

In more detail:
In your first example you pass the Hash to your foo-method. The reference will be copied, so within the foo-method you have a copy of the reference which points to the same object as 'hash_test', but is not the same one. So calling the Hash methods changes the values of the object outside of the method. But in your second example your are not changing values of the given Hash, you assign a new Hash object to the copy of the method reference, which has no effect to the 'hash_test' reference.

Comment: And because of that, Ruby is not "pass by value" but "pass by reference".

Comment: @HolgerJust: Ruby is *not* pass-by-reference, it is pass-by-value. Always. No exceptions. If it *were* pass-by-reference, then we wouldn't have this conversation because the OP's code would have worked as he expected and he never would have asked this question. Don't believe me? Ask Ruby: `def foo(bar) bar = 'reference' end; baz = 'value'; foo(baz); puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}"`

Comment: Well, in your method you are assigning `baz` with a new variable and not update the reference. Try this instead (which keeps the reference): `def foo(bar) bar.replace('reference'); end; baz = 'value'; foo(baz); puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}"`

Comment: And besides, if it really where pass by value, each passed parameter would be copied before passing it to a method. This would be *really* slow and would now allow to e.g. change an array inplace like this: `def add(array); array << "Hello"; end`

Comment: (And what you describe in your second paragraph is exactly pass-by-reference, i.e that only a new reference to the existing object is created on method invocation, but not a whole new object)

Comment: I know that this is a controversial topic. And in my humble opinion it depends on what do you pass to the method: The object or the reference. In Ruby it is the reference, which is a address to the actual object. And this reference will be copied. So there are 2 different references which point to the same object, so that your replace-call works, because both reference point to the same replace-method. But the point is that you copy the reference (which is not really slow) and don't have the same reference inside and outside the method. A term for this i have heard is 'pass by reference value'